# Will the IBM Websphere Application Server run the Python/Jython script without Python Interpreter installed

Tags: websphere, jython, wsadmin

I am new to Python and IBM Websphere Application Server. 
I run a status.bat file which calls status.py file through wsadmin(provided username, password and status.py path passed as parameters to wsadmin). IBM Websphere Application Server is installed in the machine.What i want to know is a Python Interpreter needed to run a python script, it was not installed in the system. 
Since the script is running through a WAS server-wsadmin, it had a capability to run a PY script even without having a PY Interpreter in that machine?? by its own compiling tool??

If it is must to have PYTHON.exe installed, do i need to tell wsadmin or anywhere that it is a PY script??

NOTE: The script and .bat was already existed in the machine and im supossed to work on it. I dont have any idea of the purpose of using wsadmin to run the script instead of by directly calling script by [python status.py] in .bat

Summary :- WS server had an any internal PY Interperter??

Thanks in Advance Friends....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`WebSphere Application Server` comes with `Jython` – `Python` implementation for `JVM`. It is usually located under `<WAS_HOME>/optionalLibraries/jython`.

To run a script you can use `wsadmin`:

```
./wsadmin.sh -lang jython -f your_script.py
```

The purpose of using `wsadmin` is that it provides facilities for server administration. If you don't need those then you can probably utilize `optionalLibraries/jython/jython.jar` directly although I never did this myself.

Comment: Thank you.. it clears my doubt....
Now im able to run a PY file by passing credential through wsadmin...